# Fill css progressbar value/width when reaching a set time/date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to make a css progress bar whose width  would be defined by a date and time.

The purpose is to create a progress bar when reaching a specific predefined date and time set.

For Example: The Progressbar reaches 100% when the date is December 25, 2014.
The calculation method i think should be: [(date&time_defined) - (date&time_today)] = Value of the width percentage, so when [(date&time_defined)==(date&time_today)] width percentage should be 100%.

This is the progressbar css code that i use

```
     <html>
   <body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
     $(function() {
            $(".meter > span").each(function() {
                $(this)
                    .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
                    .width(0)
                    .animate({
                        width: $(this).data("origWidth")
                    }, 1200);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .meter { 
            height: 20px;  /* Can be anything */
            position: relative;
            margin: 60px 0 20px 0; /* Just for demo spacing */
            background: #555;
            -moz-border-radius: 25px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 10px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            -moz-box-shadow   : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            box-shadow        : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        }
        .meter > span {
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
               -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
                   -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
                       border-top-right-radius: 8px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
             -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
                    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
                 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
                        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
                     border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
              linear,
              left bottom,
              left top,
              color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)),
              color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84))
             );
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
              center bottom,
              rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
              rgb(84,240,84) 69%
             );
            -webkit-box-shadow: 
              inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
              inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            -moz-box-shadow: 
              inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
              inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            box-shadow: 
              inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
              inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .meter > span:after, .animate > span > span {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
            background-image: 
               -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, 
                  color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
                  color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), 
                  color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
                  color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
                  color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent)
               );
            background-image: 
                -moz-linear-gradient(
                  -45deg, 
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
                  transparent 25%, 
                  transparent 50%, 
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
                  transparent 75%, 
                  transparent
               );
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
            -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
            -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
               -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
                   -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
                       border-top-right-radius: 8px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
             -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
                    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
                 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
                        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
                     border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .animate > span:after {
            display: none;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes move {
            0% {
               background-position: 0 0;
            }
            100% {
               background-position: 50px 50px;
            }
        }

        .orange > span {
            background-color: #f1a165;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1a165, #f36d0a);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #f1a165),color-stop(1, #f36d0a));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1a165, #f36d0a); 
        }

        .red > span {
            background-color: #f0a3a3;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #f0a3a3),color-stop(1, #f42323));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0a3a3, #f42323);
        }

        .nostripes > span > span, .nostripes > span:after {
            -webkit-animation: none;
            background-image: none;
        }
    </style>


    <div class="meter">
            <span style="width: PERCENTAGE%"></span>
        </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

If possible do show me the needed code to use inside the  above code because I'm not familiar much with CSS and javascript or whatsoever. I'm just trying to start :)

EDIT: I just need a modification to the code above so it would work when i insert a date $ time(e.g. december, 25, 2014 14:08) into wherever provided.. instead of a fixed width

Comment: What is your question? are you asking us to provide you with the code? or is there a problem with the code you posted above that needs fixing?

Comment: actually its a modification.
The code above works perfectly when you plugin in a percentage for the width. what i want is instead to plugin a percentage, i would plug in a date with time so it shows the remaining time left via the graphical progress bar.

Comment: Nice question.  Will you have multiple progress bars?  Your selector in your JQuery seems to indicate that you might.  I'm working on a fiddle now, hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid way to convert the dates into numbers (the easiest way is to use milliseconds).  You also need a reference point to use for calculations (let's use the start of the year).

Once you have these things, the formula is straightforward.  Here is the pseudo code:

```
(difference of current from start date / difference of final date from start date) * 100
```

In JS:

```
var targetDate = new Date("12/25/2014");
var beginDate = new Date("01/01/2014");
var totalTime = (targetDate - beginDate);
var dateProgress = new Date(data.Date) - beginDate;
var completionPercentage = (Math.round((dateProgress / totalTime) * 100));
```

Then it becomes a matter of code structure.  I like to use custom events in JQuery to keep the code DRY so below is how I solved it:

```
var targetDate = new Date("12/25/2014");
var beginDate = new Date("01/01/2014");
var totalTime = (targetDate - beginDate);
$(function () {

    //Create a custom event on the span to handle incoming data for animation.
    $(".meter > span").bind("progress-event", function (e, data) {
        $(this)
            .width($(this).prop("width"))
            .data("origWidth", data.Complete)
            .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth") + "%"
        }, 1200);
        $(this).prop("title",($(this).data("origWidth") + "%"));
    });
    //Initial animation on page load.
    $(".meter > span").each(function () {
        $(document).trigger("date-changed", {
            Date: new Date() // today's date
        });
    });

    //Apply the datepicker with an event handler for a selected date
    $("#date-input").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (selectedDate, obj) {
            $(document).trigger("date-changed", {
                Date: selectedDate
            });
        } // end onSelect function
    });
});

//Custom event to handle a date being picked from the datepicker
$(document).bind("date-changed", function (e, data) {
    var dateProgress = new Date(data.Date) - beginDate;
    var completionPercentage = (Math.round((dateProgress / totalTime) * 100));
    if(completionPercentage > 100) {  //Make sure we don't go past 100
        completionPercentage = 100;
    } // end if
    $(".meter > span").trigger("progress-event", {
        Date: data.Date,
        Complete: completionPercentage
    });
});
```

Here, I have created two custom events: `date-changed` and `progress-event`.  The `date-changed` event I have for demo purposes and is triggered when a date is selected from the date picker on the text box.  This feeds the "selected" date to the `progress-event` after performing some calculations.  The responsibility of the `progress-event` is simply to populate the data of and animate the progress bar.

The important part is in the `$(document).trigger(......` sections where I give the name of the event I've triggered, and I build a JavaScript object that contains the data each method needs (in your case, a date object).

**Here is a JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/pzgxuoj9/

Notice that I used JQuery UI, and a newer version of JQuery than you.  JQuery UI is not necessary (unless you want to use that for picking dates) and this code should work with your version of JQuery (you may have to substitute where I used the `prop` method with calls to `attr`).  Also important to note is that I put this code in the `HEAD` section of the HTML, not the body.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! :)

but what would i really want is to put the target date with time also as predefined not as a input box. the place which i am going to use is not for user selection. mainly its going to be used as a website under construction progress  bar with a preset time when it will finish.

Hope you get what i mean :)

Comment: @mpuria Yes, you don't need the datepicker, instead, just use today's date and trigger the event on page load.

Comment: ok. how about the time also, for example i want it to set to complete at 12/24/2014 23:59. with the time i mean :)

Comment: @mpuria The constructor of the JavaScript date object allows you to pass in many different formats for dates, so instead of specifying the targetDate as above, you can say: `targetDate = new Date("12/24/2014 23:59:59");` or `targetDate = new Date("2014", "12", "24", "23", "59", "59", "00");`. See here for more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: this is what i have done, but not working
[http://jsfiddle.net/028zca8L/](http://jsfiddle.net/028zca8L/)

Comment: @mpuria I have updated my answer and my fiddle to populate on load.  To make it work the way you want, trigger the `"date-changed"` event (and omit the Completed argument) instead of the `progress-event`.

Comment: great!, works perfectly!!! but just one last thing... im trying to make it work with html but when i open it in browser, the progress bar is always at 100%. Heres what i have done http://pastebin.com/YQtWnkcG

Comment: @mpuria You are referencing JavaScript and style in the body.  Try moving the JQuery include, your style, and the custom JS code into the `<head>` section of your html, instead of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
 <script>
 $(function(){
   setTimeout(progressBar, 100);
 });
 function progressBar(){
    var oldValue=$('.progressbar').val();
    $('.progressbar').val(oldValue+1);
    setTimeout(progressBar, 100);
  }
</script>
<progress class="progressbar" value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: where should i put it?? sorry, im just new into css and java :)

Comment: just you copy this code and paste it in your html file and run it. The progress bar increase each min i kept. you want to increase the time, you can.

Answer (score 0):

** PROGRESS BAR FILL ACCORDING TO THE TIME AS SECOUNDS **

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100); // set time ex: 100 as 10s 
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
return false;
}
```

```css
<style>

#label {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: white;
}
.meter {
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 60px 0 20px 0;
    background: #555;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.meter > span {
    display: block;
    width:1%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84)) );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(43,194,83) 37%, rgb(84,240,84) 69% );
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.meter > span:after, .animate > span > span {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent) );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent );
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    -webkit-animation: move 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body onload="move()">



<div id="myProgress" class="meter">
  <span id="myBar">
    <center><div id="label">1%</div></center>
  </span>
</div>

<br>




</body>
```